# SharePoint Online : Restructuring sharepoint document folder into metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata

I have multiple folder in document library. I want to change it into metadata. So i don't need to use folder anymore to manage document. Is there anyway I can do that without installing other software? I just want to use existing features in SharePoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found the answer by myself from this link : http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/08/02/sharepoint-convert-folder-structures-to-metadata-aspx/

The trick is to add a metadata column in all of files in folder and then set folder to not display in document library. After that move the file outside of folder via explorer